# Table join with case

Tags: mysql

We would have to   join 4 tables based on the table 1 column itemtype.

> table A contains id,itemtype,itemid
>
> table  B contains id, fullname
>
> table c contains id, fullname
>
> table D contains id, fullname
>
> Table A.itemid is in(table B or table C or table D) of id.

I want to join Table A   with remaing tables  to get full name. based on the TableA column itemtype  value join another one table

```
     select
     tblA.itemid,y.fullname from tableA as tblA 
      inner join (
        CASE WHEN tblA.itemtype = 1 THEN 
          select
            tblB.itemid as id,tblB.fullname  as fullname
          from
            tableB    as tblB 
          where
            tblB.id = tblA.itemid
        WHEN tblA.itemtype = 2 THEN  
          select
            tblC.itemid as id,tblC.fullname  as fullname
          from
            tableC  as tblC  
          where
            tblC.id = tblA.itemid
            WHEN tblA.itemtype = 3 THEN 
              select
            tblD.itemid as id ,tblD.fullname as fullname
          from
            tableD  as tblD  
          where
            tblD.id = tblA.itemid

          END
      ) as bcd on bcd.id = tblA.itemid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `left join` the tables `B`, `C` and `D` to table A and include the condition for the column `itemtype` in the `ON` clause:

```
select
  A.itemid,
  coalesce(B.fullname, C.fullname, D.fullname) fullname
from A 
left join B on B.id = A.itemid AND A.itemtype = 1
left join C on C.id = A.itemid AND A.itemtype = 2
left join D on D.id = A.itemid AND A.itemtype = 3
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/55hCCBRAvotendszCBeAYT/0).
Or with UNION ALL:

```
select
  A.itemid,
  B.fullname
from A inner join B on B.id = A.itemid 
where A.itemtype = 1
union all
select
  A.itemid,
  C.fullname
from A inner join C on C.id = A.itemid 
where A.itemtype = 2
union all
select
  A.itemid,
  D.fullname
from A inner join D on D.id = A.itemid 
where A.itemtype = 3
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/55hCCBRAvotendszCBeAYT/1).

Comment: Great Aksen,

It is working good. But the problem is tables are   unnecessary joined event though the  itemetype not related. 

Ex: if itemtype =1 , unnecessary joined TableC and Table D. So it is impacted on the performance.

Comment: Who is Aksen? The reason for the joins is that you can't join B or C or D in a condition (at least not without dynamic sql). You know that because you tried to do it in your query. The code in my answer is what you can do. Also even if it could be done, it would be far less efficient to check a condition and join one table or the other each time. The joins in my code are necessary so each row of A is joined actually to only one table's rows because of the condition AND A.itemtype = ?

Comment: The other way that you could achieve the same is by UNION ALL, but this would scan the table 3 times and then apply UNION.

Answer (score 0):

If there are not many columns in the association tables:

```
SELECT
   a.itemid,
   COALESCE(b.fullname, c.fullname, d.fullname, ' - Missing name - '))
FROM
   tblA a 
   LEFT JOIN tblB b ON a.itemtype = 1 AND a.itemid = a.id
   LEFT JOIN tblC c ON a.itemtype = 2 AND a.itemid = b.id
   LEFT JOIN tblD d ON a.itemtype = 3 AND a.itemid = c.id
```